# get selected element containing specific word on text - jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to check if selected item contains specific word. Ex:

```
  <select name='project_type' id='type'>
  <option value='1'>Interpretation - S</option>
  <option value='2'>Interpretation - K</option>
  <option value='5'>Editing</option>
  <option value='7'>Translation</option>
  </select>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#work1").show();
       $("#work2").hide();
        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id selected
       $("#type").live('click', function(){

        // If checked
        if (!$("#type:selected").text(contains('interpretation')))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#work1").show();
                    $("#work2").hide();
        }
        else    if ($("#type:selected").text(contains('interpretation')))
        {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#work2").show();
                    $("#work1").hide();
        }
      });

    });
</script>
```

I need to get the selected element which contains 'interpretation' on text (i want all elements containing that word). I made this :`$("#type:selected").text(contains('interpretation'))` but doesn't function. 
Please, anybody can help?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#type').change(function() {
    if ($(this).find(':selected').text().indexOf('Interpretation') > -1) {
        alert('selected value contains interpretation');    
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HyG6D/

Comment: I ended up having to something similar and this was a great help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
index = $("#type:selected").text().indexOf('interpreatation');
if(index == -1)
    //Show
else
    //Hide
```

JavaScript doesn't have any function called `contains` and a known work around is to do a check for the index of a specific phrase or word. If it doesn't exist then it returns -1.

Edit: Changed the Hide/Show from the question's code.

Comment: @Faust: even though it has the same name - it's 100% irrelevant to the question

Comment: @zerkms: Right. I just realized the asker mis-used .contains(). My answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'type' is the id of your *select* tag, your selector  will not work.The `:selected` pseudo-selector needs to be on the *option* tag, not the select tag. Find the selected option tag *inside* of a select tag with id='type' like this:

```
!$("#type option:selected").text(contains('interpretation')){ ...
```

See:
http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

"The :selected selector works for `<option>` elements ..."

**update**: I failed to notice that your formulation is not using `.contains`  properly.
.contains() tests whether one DOM element contains another. So, instead, combine my above advice on selectors with Zerkim's solution, to arrive at:

```
!$("#type option:selected").text().indexOf('Interpretation') > -1)
```

...for your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that could help?

```
$("#type option").each(function(k,v){

    if($(v).text().indexOf('interpreatation') != -1){

       //do something or add element to an array


    }

});
```

Comment: "Is this something that could help?" --- you're not sure yourself?